# And condition in IN CLAUSE in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 1 table say tbl

```
id       aid         bid
-------------------------
 1        100         1
 2        101         4
 3        100         4
 4        103         3
```

I want the value of aid which is common for bid values 1 and 4 so i used in clause

```
select aid from tbl where bid in(1,4)
```

but it will give me all the records having bid 1 or 4 -- (100 and 101 in this case)

my requirement is to use and condition (i.e. record having bid 1 and 4 -- (100 in this case)

So Please tell me how can i get this.......

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT aid 
FROM tbl 
Where bid = 1 And exists (select aid from tbl Where bid = 4)
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a30abc/4)**

Op:

```
+----+
|aid |
+----+
|100 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use [exists](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

```
select t1.aid from tbl t1 
where t1.bid = 1
and exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.aid = t1.aid and t2.bid = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join like:

```
select t1.aid
from tbl t1
join tbl t2
ON t1.aid=t2.aid 
and t2.bid=4 and t1.bid=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will SUM the appearance of bid in(1,4). You can search for DISTINCT aid with any number of bids:

```
SELECT aid FROM tbl
GROUP BY aid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN bid IN(1,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2;
```

In case you have duplicated data on (`aid, bid`), ex:

```
id       aid         bid
-------------------------
 1        100         1
 2        101         4
 3        100         4 <--
 4        103         3
 5        100         4 <--
```

Change to this:

```
SELECT res.aid FROM (SELECT DISTINCT aid, bid FROM tbl) res
GROUP BY res.aid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN res.bid IN(1,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2;
```

SQL Fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cf44/18)